# Format POSIXct date to DDMMMYYYY format in R

Tags: r, posixct

I have a date column that is formatted like this:

```
> head(date)
[1] "2019-11-12 10:55:27 EST" "2019-11-12 14:52:10 EST" "2019-11-13 11:38:59 EST" "2019-11-12 13:37:58 EST"
[5] "2019-11-12 11:15:45 EST" "2019-11-12 11:38:08 EST"
```

I would like it to be formatted as DDMMMYYYY (e.g. 12NOV2019). Is there a way to convert to this format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `format`

```
format(as.POSIXct(date), "%d%b%Y")
#[1] "12Nov2019" "12Nov2019" "13Nov2019" "12Nov2019" "12Nov2019" "12Nov2019"
```

If your `date` is already of class `POSIXct` so you can remove the `as.POSIXct` part.

**data**

```
date <- c("2019-11-12 10:55:27 EST", "2019-11-12 14:52:10 EST", 
          "2019-11-13 11:38:59 EST", "2019-11-12 13:37:58 EST",
          "2019-11-12 11:15:45 EST", "2019-11-12 11:38:08 EST")
```